# Solr relevancy for search term based on where it occurs in field

Tags: search, solr

I'm working on Solr 3.6.

For following keyword:

ipod

I get following results in same order as listed.

Logitech Bedside Dock for Ipod
Logitech S135i portable Ipod Speaker
Edifier Image iF330 Plus i-pod Docking station with Remote
JBL On Stage Micro II Portable iPod Speaker and Docking Station
Apple iPod Nano 8GB
Apple iPod Shuffle 2GB

I want to instruct solr to list those results where the search term comes earlier in the name. So the last two should be the first two. Apart from that do some kind of analysis where importance of the search term be calculated on the total length. So the shorter name with search term should come early.

I'm clueless how to do this, pls advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it two ways at least

1. using payloads: see [this](http://searchhub.org/dev/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/) or [this](http://edwarddrapkin.com/2011/04/14/an-introduction-to-lucene-payloads/). But you need to develop some code to use them from Solr (see the first article)
2. using several additional fields: say, you add 5 additional fields, and you put the first word in the first field, 2nd in 2nd field etc. And when querying you add an OR so those fields are searched too, each having a decreasing boost. This solution is less than ideal, but you avoid having to write any java code.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Isn't there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: How to implement the second option?